# binary generation from LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

How does one generate executable binaries from the c++ side of LLVM?

I'm currently writing a toy compiler, and I'm not quite sure how to do the final step of creating an executable from the IR.

The only solution I currently see is to write out the bitcode and then call llc using `system` or the like. Is there a way to do this from the c++ interface instead?

This seems like it would be a common question, but I can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LLVM does not ship the linker necessary to perform this task. It can only write out as assembler and then invoke the system linker to deal with it. You can see the source code of `llvm-ld` to see how it's done.

Comment: If you read llvm-ld's documentation, it says that its output is still bytecode, not a native binary. The bytecode it outputs is indeed linked in the sense that all the inputs are present in the output. In order to act as a drop in replacement for ld, llvm-ld must generate the usual a.out file, but its also not a native executable. It is a shell script which invokes LLVM's lli utility which then executes the bytecode (either via its interpreter or via JIT compilation). If you really want an executable, you ultimately have to compile your LLVM IR or bytecode into assembly and run it through gcc.